# Video inside webview is not playing

Tags: android-webview

Hey guys I am new to Android. My video inside webview is not playing on mobile devices. But it does play on tablet.
what would be the problem? Below is my code. Please help me with this.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    WebView web;
    ImageView img,bckimg,share_btn;
    String content,shareUrl;
    String movYear, movName, movImage, movDirector, movAwards; 
    String movProducer, movActedAs, movAnecdotes, movSynopsis; 
    boolean thisUrl = false;
    ImageView showProgress;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);


        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        showProgress=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.showProgress);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.header);
        bckimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wbview_bckbtn);
        share_btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.share_btn);

        web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
        web.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");

        web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        if(bundle!=null)
        {
            int tab_value = bundle.getInt("tab_value");

            if(tab_value==1){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar_latest);

                thisUrl = false;
            }else if(tab_value==2){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar_dance);
                thisUrl = false;
            }else if(tab_value==3){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar_movies);
                thisUrl = true;
            }else if(tab_value==4){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar_fashion);
                thisUrl = false;
            }else if(tab_value==5){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar_health);
                thisUrl = false;

            }else if(tab_value==6){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar_art);
                thisUrl = false;
            }


            if(!thisUrl){
                share_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                content =   bundle.getString("content");
                web.loadData("<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\" /><title>Madhuri Dixit-Nene</title><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"all\" href=\"http://madhuridixit-nene.com/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css\" /><style type=\"text/css\">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style><style type=\"text/css\">p {padding:5px !important;margin:5px !important;}</style></head><body class=\"single single-post postid-1606 single-format-standard single-author singular two-column right-sidebar\"><div class=\"entry-content\">"+content+"</div></body></html>","text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
                shareUrl=bundle.getString("shareUrl");
            }else{
                share_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                movYear     =   bundle.getString("movieYear");
                movName     =   bundle.getString("movieName");
                movImage        =   bundle.getString("movieImage");
                movAwards       =   bundle.getString("movieAwards");
                movDirector =   bundle.getString("movieDirector");
                movProducer =   bundle.getString("movieProducer");
                movActedAs  =   bundle.getString("movieActedAs");
                movAnecdotes    =   bundle.getString("movieAnecdotes");
                movSynopsis =   bundle.getString("movieSynopsis");

                web.loadData("<p style='text-align:center'><img class='aligncenter size-full wp-image-1607' title='' src="+movImage+" alt='' width='240px' height='180px' /></p><p><center><U><H2>"+movName+"("+movYear+")</H2></U></center></p><p><strong>Director : </strong>"+movDirector+"</p><p><strong>Producer : </strong>"+movProducer+"</p><p><strong>Character : </strong>"+movActedAs+"</p><p><strong>Summary : </strong>"+movAnecdotes+"</p><p><strong>Synopsis : </strong>"+movSynopsis+"</p>\n","text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
                shareUrl=bundle.getString("shareUrl");
            }
        }

        bckimg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
            }
        });

        share_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override


            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Madhuri");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareUrl);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_web_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        // show the web page in webview but not in web browser
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            view.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            view.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            view.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
            view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }



        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            showProgress.clearAnimation();
            showProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            showProgress.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate));

            showProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
        /*  super.onBackPressed();*/

    }
}
```

and also explain to me what is the difference between WebViewClient and WebViewChromeClient?

Answer (score 0):

please add hardwareaccelerated set as true in your android manifest file. android 3.0+ we have to enabled this feature then only video supports. You certainly can use both, they just have different functions. Setting your own custom WebViewClient lets you handle onPageFinished, shouldOverrideUrlLoading, etc., WebChromeClient lets you handle Javascript's alert() and other functions.